# Estou com problemas de import e export usando ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estou usando o Google Chrome como browser e quando eu tento rodar o código, aparece este erro. E eu vi que no arquivo HTML eu posso usar o type="module", porém, aparece outros dois erros. O primeiro erro é sem o type="module", e os dois de baixo são com o type="module"

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>
> Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/Vagner%20Wentz/Desktop/cursoes6/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
>
> GET file:///C:/Users/Vagner%20Wentz/Desktop/cursoes6/main.js net::ERR_FAILED

```
//funcoes.js
export function soma(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

//main.js
import { soma } from './funcoes.js';

console.log(soma(1, 2));
```

Comment: Você ta tentando abrir direto no navegador ou o app ta rodando em algum servidor web?

Comment: Estou usando um webpack server que o Diego da rocketseat ensinou a instalar

Comment: Adiciona o que é necessário pra reproduzir seu problema na pergunta, senão fica difícil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ta acontencendo porque você ta importando o main.js junto com o bundle.js. O main.js contém o código não transpilado, por isso do erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Só remover o main.js.

Answer (score 1):

Vai na configuração do seu webserver no webpack e adiciona:

```js
headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
```

Comment: Em qualquer lugar do webpack?

Comment: onde tem ```new WebpackDevServer(...,{  adiciona os headers aqui } ); ```

Comment: Elabore um pouco mais a resposta explicando o porquê do erro e em qual caso sua solução resolveria o problema